# Error executing sftp with curl

Tags: linux, sftp, curl

I'm using IBM's Data Explorer to import certain data, but am getting this error:

> *Protocol sftp not supported or disabled in libcurl.*

So from Red Hat I manually ran the command:

```
curl -user sftp://hostname.com/~/filename.csv
```

But got this error:

> *curl: (51) SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK*

To see if SFTP is supported I ran `curl -V` and got following:

> *curl 7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.14.0.0 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18  libssh2/1.4.2 Protocols: tftp ftp telnet dict ldap ldaps http file https ftps scp sftp*

Does anyone know what could be wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you key is bad.  However there is a remote chance that if this worked previously, the server you are attempting to connect to is having a problem.

Comment: I've never had it work. How do I make this key good (I'm not even sure which key)? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IBM Data Explorer is probably linked against its own private copy of libcurl, so what you see in the system version may not be reflective of the IBM version as far as `sftp` support.

Normally, curl works like this:

```
curl -u <username> sftp://hostname.com/~/filename.csv
```

This assumes you have successfully run `ssh hostname.com` before, which should have added the right key entry to your `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file. If for some reason this is problematic, you could add `-k` to the curl command line to disable the SSH host key check.

Answer (score 1):

This is a issue with curl command line tool where by default it checks for host key in the file ~/.ssh/known_hosts . If not then connection will be closed and file will not get downloaded. To add the key to ~/.ssh/known_hosts run the below command

```
ssh-keyscan -t rsa host_name  >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

The libcurl on the other hand doesn't perform the default host key check and you will not face this issue. In summary the default behavior should be same but it is not.